# How to check the log of netcat during ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, netcat, logs

I use netcat to do the traffic forwarding during 3 machine(A->B->C) ssh tunneling. The proxy command from host A running on host B is like:

```
/usr/bin/ssh host_B nc localhost 19999
```

And there exists a tunnel between host_B:19999 and host_C:22

I would like to know what has been done by netcat. Where is the netcat log file? I tried to issue the below proxy command on A:

```
/usr/bin/ssh host_B nc -vv localhost 19999 > log.txt 2>&1
```

But it always gives me "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" on host A

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netcat doesn't log anything.

Redirecting the output of netcat to a file breaks your setup because that output is supposed to go to the `ssh` process. With the redirection you set up, the data sent by the remote host ends up in `log.txt` instead of being sent to the client. If you only want to log errors, use `2>log.txt`.

If you want to dump all the data transmitted by netcat to a file, you need to duplicate it.

```
unbuffer tee input.data | nc localhost 19999 | unbuffer tee output.data
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I  replaced ">log.txt 2>&1" with "2>log.txt". It only stores the log info on host_A while my intention is store it on host_B where the traffic forwarding occurs. Do you know what's the correct syntax for it?

Comment: Oh. I see. Just wrap the "nc -vv localhost 19999 2>log.txt" with quotes will work!